# What is the difference between scroll api and search after elastic search api

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

What is the difference between scroll api and search after elastic search API. Which is better for retrieving more than 50000 records at a time?

Comment: What is the senario to retrieve more than 50000 records at a time ?

Comment: its for generating the report and exporting the data to csv file

Comment: "We no longer recommend using the scroll API for deep pagination. If you need to preserve the index state while paging through more than 10,000 hits, use the search_after parameter with a point in time (PIT)."